# VFIO Passthrough NVIDIA on Kubuntu 18.04/20.04. ERROR: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, kvm-virtualization

I'm attempting to passthrough NVIDIA on Kubuntu 18.04/20.04 (have both operating systems installed). I've followed all the steps in this article "https://blog.zerosector.io/2018/07/28/kvm-qemu-windows-10-gpu-passthrough/". IOMMU & VFIO is enabled according to "dmesg | grep -E "DMAR|IOMMU" and "dmesg | grep -i vfio". But the Kernel driver in use doesn't change to VFIO.

"lspci -vnn" returns the following

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 980] [10de:13c0] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 980] [10de:1116]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
        Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fbb] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:1116]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

After some researching I found "https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF/" and tried with the following code in GRUB (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text intel_iommu=on vfio-pci.ids=10de:0fbb,10de:13c0). But this freezes the computer and gives the following error https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgTxp.jpg

```
vfio-pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
```

When changing so the GRUB only enables the VFIO on the nvidia audio ("GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text intel_iommu=on vfio-pci.ids=10de:0fbb") it works and "lspci -vnn" returns the code down below. The only thing that doesn't work is to passthrough the graphics card, which causes the computer to freeze on startup.

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 980] [10de:13c0] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 [GeForce GTX 980] [10de:1116]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 34
        Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
        Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia

01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fbb] (rev a1)
        Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation GM204 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:1116]
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
        Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Any help is very appreciated.

EDIT: I have given up, check out https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/g58ppr/giving_20_usd_10191_dogecoins_to_anyone_who_can/. You might find some good answers there.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?